# Solving the diffrence equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the difference equation:

$a_{n+2}^3=a_{n+1}+a_{n}^2$

Given $a_0=a_1=1$

Anyway, is there a generalized way to solve all difference equations?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method general enough to solve all difference equations like this.  Linear difference equations with polynomial coefficients are the most general difference equations that can be solved using pure technique—at least, so far as I know.  This one looks like it was written down at random (perhaps just adding exponents to the Fibonacci recursion?); I would be very surprised if it had a closed form solution, unless it was designed specifically to have one.

I would love to be proven wrong, and be told that this is some famous problem and it requires such-and-such beautiful theory.  But if this problem was taken from somewhere, then I bet it was not taken faithfully—perhaps the original problem was to compute asymptotics or something, but not the full solution.